# Finding the Final Position from Original Position + Offset and Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my Building System almost finished; the problem is when I debugged my `Physics.OverlapBox()`, by using a `Gizmos.DrawWireCube()` with the code shown below:

```c#
void OnGizmosDraw()
{
     Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position + boundingOffset, transform.rotation, boundingExtents);
     Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one);
}
```

I saw the problem but I will show it in an image, since I am kind of struggling to explain.

[image]

I have thought of a solution but I could not find the equations and what method it is. Basically, there is an Original Vector to which an Offset will be added (if defined) and have it's Final Vector affected by Rotation. It is explained more in another.

[image]

Maybe it is a trigonometry based calculation. I hope you could find how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `boundingOffset` and `boundingExtends`?

Comment: `boundingOffset` is where the center of the box would be at and the `boundingExtents` is the size of the Box. Basically I use those to create an OverlapBox, the `boundingOffset` will be added position relative to the position of the Parent (`transform.position` + `boundingOffset`) but the problem is the Parent Object has a Rotation. It is good for Child Components to just Get it but for the Code I needed, the position is still (`transform.position` + `boundingOffset`) with no effect of the Rotation of the Parent Object

Comment: So the problem seems to be in code you didn't show us? Could you include then the implementation where you are using the `Physics.OverlapBox`? I don't understand currently if the question is about `Gizmos` and not showing correct positions or if it is rather with the `Physics.OverlapBox` not using the box you expected? And with `what is` I ment how do you calculate `boundingOffset` and `boundingExtends`?

Comment: it would be this line of code:

`Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.position + boundingOffset, boundingExtents / 2, blueprint.transform.rotation);`

The `boundingOffset` and `boundingExtents` is a constant variable depending on the object and it has the same implementation as the `Box Collider` settings has.

Comment: So your main question seems to be how do I convert that `boundingOffset` and `boundingExtents` world coordinates into ones relative to the transform position and rotation, right? Like the thing you do in the Gizmos using the `Matrix4x4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if I understand you correctly this time the issue is that your offset works as long as the transform isn't scaled or rotated.

The reason is that

```
transform.position + boundingOffset
```

uses plain worldspace coordinates. As you can see the offset from orange to red dot is exactly the same (in world coordinates) in both pictures.

What you rather want is an offset relative to the `transform` position and scale. You can convert your `boundingOffset` to local coordinates relative to the transform by using [`TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

> Transforms `position` from local space to world space.

So instead use

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.TransformPoint(boundingOffset), boundingExtents / 2, blueprint.transform.rotation);
```

What it does is basically

```
transform.position 
    + transform.right * boundingOffset.x * transform.lossyScale.x 
    + transform.up * boundingOffset.y * transform.lossyScale.y
    + transform.forward * boundingOffset.z * transform.lossyScale.z;
```

---

#### Alternatively

A bit more maintainable approach I often use in such a case is not providing `boundingOffset` via a hardocded/field vector but instead simply use a child GameObject e.g. called `OffsetPivot` and place it in the scene however you want. Since it is a child of your `transform` it will always keep the correct offset when you rotate/scale/move the parent.

Then in the code I would simply do

```
[SerializeField] private Transform boundingOffsetPivot;

...

Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(boundingOffsetPivot.position, boundingExtents / 2, blueprint.transform.rotation);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that it would have so many Complex Math but it was just solved by a Single Function